# C# Using a variable to access a Windows Form Control

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to Update a number of listView controls (i.e. listView1,ListView2,ListView3 etc)

I am getting an syntax error in Visual Studio 2015.

I have broken this down to the basic issue so the error can be isolated. the following is the code I have

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("Task", "Task");
        Control[] TestlistView = this.Controls.Find("listView1", true);
        TestlistView[0].Columns.Add("Task22", "Task22");
    }
```

The first code line is valid. I have placed it there to simply ensure access to listView1 is Ok.

I am getting the syntax issue on line 3 (TestlistView[0].Columns.Add).

The error is 
'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My confusion is that when I comment out line 3 and debug and set a breakpoint after "this.Controls.Find" I can see "TestlistView" in the locals watch window and it all looks good - the control has been found.

Uncomment out line 3 and visual studio highlights the .Columns. with the error detailed above.

Any assistance or guidence in solving the basic issue will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to cast `TestlistView[0]` to a tree view.

Answer (score 0):

Controls.Find returns objects that are of type Control.  Those objects can be of any type that inherit from Control.  The compiler has no way of determining exactly what type of control you are looking for, and so it gives an error when you try to access properties that are not part of Control.

You can fix this by telling the compiler what type you expect.  You can do this by either adding an expicit cast, using Linq and the OfType function or using the "as" operator to attempt to cast the results to the right type.